# Exception when reading BigQuery from Dataflow template using ValueProvider

Tags: java, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I'm trying to create a template to read from BigQuery, unfortunately I get an exception trying to build the template.

> **An exception occured while executing the Java class. Cannot call validate if table is dynamically set.**

Reading [the documentation](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/templates/creating-templates#pipeline-io-and-runtime-parameters), it seems that there's a special function to call when reading BigQuery from batch template :

> **Note**: If you want to run a batch pipeline that reads from BigQuery,
>   you must use **.withTemplateCompatibility()** on all BigQuery reads.

So, here's my code snippet :

```
PCollection<Discount> discountFromBigQuery = p.apply("Parse Discounts from BigQuery", BigQueryIO.read((SerializableFunction<SchemaAndRecord, Discount>) record -> {
        GenericRecord row = record.getRecord();
        return new Discount(row);
    }).withTemplateCompatibility().from(options.getBigQueryDiscountPath()).withCoder(SerializableCoder.of(Discount.class)));
```

Obviously, `options.getBigQueryDiscountPath()` is a `ValueProvider<String>`

So, how can I get rid of this error and template the BigQuery reading part ?

Here are the maven dependencies I use  :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.beam</groupId>
    <artifactId>beam-sdks-java-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.8.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.beam</groupId>
    <artifactId>beam-sdks-java-io-google-cloud-platform</artifactId>
    <version>2.8.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.cloud.dataflow</groupId>
    <artifactId>google-cloud-dataflow-java-sdk-all</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the error you are facing is defined [here](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/master/sdks/java/io/google-cloud-platform/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/gcp/bigquery/BigQueryIO.java#L684). Please note the explanation, that mentions

> Note that a  table or query check can fail if the table or dataset are created
>   by earlier stages of the pipeline or if a query depends on earlier
>   stages of a pipeline.

To overcome this, try adding the [withoutValidation method](https://beam.apache.org/releases/javadoc/2.8.0/index.html?org/apache/beam/sdk/io/gcp/bigquery/BigQueryIO.html) in your BigQueryIO.read call.

Comment: Yeah, I managed to generate a template using this method. But what validations do this method perform ?

Comment: According to the docs, withoutValidation method disables: Validation that the  table exists or the query succeeds before submitting the pipeline. Validation that a query or a table is specified still occurs.

Answer (score 1):

By the way, withoutValidation() needs to be added at the end of the chain like below.

```
    // queryString is of type ValueProvider<String>
    PCollection<TableRow> rowsFromBigQuery = pipeline.apply(
                BigQueryIO.readTableRows()
                        .fromQuery(queryString)
                        .usingStandardSql()
                        .withMethod(options.getReadMethod())
                        .withoutValidation());
```